# scanner closed exception within main method

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, java.util.scanner, finally

Can someone please highlight to me the problem With my main method? I am getting the error exception that scanner is closed once I complete first option and try to enter another?

I think the problem I am having is from the placement of my try catch and finally blocks but not totally sure! Thanks!

```
/**
 * Scanner used for input within program
 */
public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * Main method that provides user with a menu in which each number
 * represents a different task in which they can carry out
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {



int menuOption=0;
do{ 
    try {

        // Declaring var for user Input (defaulted to 0)
        menuOption = showMenu();
        switch (menuOption) {

        case 1:
            add();
            break;
        case 2:
            subtract();
            break;
        case 3:
            generateRandomNumber();
            guessRandomNumber();
            break;
        case 4: // invoke print loop method (use params here to get
                // experience!)
            break;
        case 5: // invoke print sum and average
            break;
        case 6: System.out.println("Quitting Program...");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");

        }// End of switch statement

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //flush scanner
        scanner.next();
    }

    finally {
        // Finally block ensures scanner is always closed
        scanner.close();
    }

}while(menuOption!=6);

//Exiting message
System.out.println("Thanks for using this Program...");
```

Comment: well you're closing the `Scanner` in the finally block so it wont be able to read after the 1st iteration...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first iteration of the loop you are closing the scanner in the finally block. The finally block goes off every time, even if a exception isn't caught.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using exceptions for program flow (and catch-all at that!)? Don't. Exceptions are very expensive and using them for program flow clutters the code a lot.

You're using `scanner.next()` in your `catch` statement: this will ask for new input.
But since the `finally` block is executed right after the `catch`, you'll immediatly close it.

The `finally` block will execute regardless of exceptions or not. It is meant to clean up resources, but you're cleaning them too early.

Remove the try-catch (or make it more appropriate) and don't close your scanner in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Close the scanner outside of the loop and get rid of the finally

```
do {
   ...
} while (...)

scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your flow of control looks like this

```
do {
    try {
        //read from scanner
    }
    finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
} while (menuOption != 6);
```

but this closes your scanner after first iteration.

You probably should move your `do...while()` inside `try{...}` block.

```
try {
    do{
        //read from scanner
    }
    while (menuOption != 6);
}
finally {
    scanner.close();
}
```

This way your `finally` block which ensures closing of scanner will be outside of loop.

Comment: By doing this does that mean that there will be no catch block?

Comment: @RNI2013 Why not? If you need one then you can place it after `try` block and before `finally`. But in your catch block you claim to flush scanner and later you invoke `scanner.next()` which most probably shouldn't be placed in `catch` but in `try`.

Comment: So you are saying not to flush the scanner in the catch section of the  code, or should scanner be flushed at all? It may be relevant to know that I have try catch in other methods of this program that flushes the code.

Comment: @RNI2013 I am not sure what do you mean by `flash` scanner. I see that you are only invoking its `next()` method which will read next found word (if there is any) and will not store it anywhere. I don't see purpose of such behaviour especially if it is depended of throwing exception before.

Answer (score -1):

Mayby you get and exception and the code enters in the catch then in finally

Tray to see if you enter in the catch block